# Image capture not display in full size in Sony Xperia MT27i?

Tags: android, camera

i create one capture app in this app i open device camera and capture the image using camera class.
my problem is when i use this app in Sony Xperia MT27i.it`s display like a below.

[image]

so i try all of the thing of camera class.and another device i tested in HTC salsa it display in full screen mode.
after capture image image result is good it`s display whole image.

now what is the problem?
Device?
else 
my Code to create camera preview?

please help any one?
Thanks.

Comment: @onik i  create app and my code is work in all other device only this (Sony Xperia) generate the problem.

Comment: @onik so think it's device problem?because of my code is run in all of the any other device very well.

Comment: Most likely it's a problem with Sony's modifications to Android, can't say since I've never used a Sony device for development. But since this is a development question, I'll migrate this to StackOverflow for you.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea for you to post the relevant parts of your code (i.e. where you set up the camera and take the picture).

Comment: @onik you are  migrate my question No problem.but after lot of search and rnd i found this is the problem of Sony Xperia Mt27i.because of  my research Instragram.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5pbnN0YWdyYW0uYW5kcm9pZCJd app witch download as a 3400000 above in this app also this type problem.so it's never any point to Migrate this question.Ok

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case with Sony Experia LT22I, when I rotate the screen with

> mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

just show about 10-20% of the view. Finally I found a solution (a patch) for this phone. Only whit change the margin Top (I don't know why) of the view this works well, like this:

```
String model = (Build.MANUFACTURER+Build.MODEL).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
if (model.equals(Constants.MODEL_EXCEPTION)) {
    final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt =(MarginLayoutParams)       
    surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    lpt.setMargins(0,-150,0,0);
    surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lpt);
}
```